# Why every Vuejs request fail in production ? error: javascript enabled

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, vue.js

I have a **vuejs app**, this app call request on a rest api in nodejs (express, mongoDB atlas), when i run the vuejs app on **localhost this work perfectly** (the nodejs app is running on a server).

When i deploy my dist folder on the server, i see the app and the display is good, but every request return this message:

> We're sorry but Monthy replay doesn't work properly without JavaScript
> enabled. Please enable it to continue. --default-noscript-error

This message com from the **noscript inside index.html (vuejs):**

```
<noscript>
    <strong>We're sorry but Monthy replay doesn't work properly without JavaScript enabled. Please 
     enable it to continue. --default-noscript-error</strong>
</noscript>
```

**I try to:**

- Edit the .htaccess
- Update the baseURL inside Axios
- Verify the proxy, and is work in local so it's good
- Check the api, call directly the api works fine

Now, i really don't know what i can try .. I don't get it why the vuejs app works but the request fail with the message from the noscript inside the index.html in vuejs.

**Update, still not work:**

In `vue.config.js` if i change the uri proxy by a dumb uri i see the same error, so something not work like i expect in production with the dist folder i thinks.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The problem is like i say in the tab update on my main post, the proxy exist in development but not in production !!

So, where you use `axios.get(uri)` you can integrate a full uri path like https://mydomain-api.com

You can create a .env file in the main vuejs with a variable:

```
VUE_APP_API_URI=http://localhost:8080
```

And for the production create a .env.production:

```
VUE_APP_API_URI=https://mydomain-api.com
```

In you'r axios get just add this:

```
axios.get(`${process.env.VUE_APP_API_URI}${uri}`)
```

Now, the request in developement target the localhost and the proxy in vue.config.js is taken. In production (npm run build and folder dist) the `.env.production` is taken and call directly the url.

You can have a cross-origin header, to fix that go on you back-end api and add cors.

Example for Nodejs project inside app.js i do:

```
// npm install cors
const cors = require('cors');
app.use(cors({
    origin: 'https://myFrontEndApp.com'
}))
```

Answer (score 1):

This occured, when you accidentally set your web directory to the /public instead of the /dist directory. After you changed the apps root to point to the /dist directory in your nginx settings it worked fine.

```
server {
    listen 443 ssl http2;
    listen [::]:443 ssl http2;
    server_name mydomain.com;
    root /path/to/my/website/dist;

    # other settings below...
}
```

Comment: I understand but i don't know why you talk about nginx settings at this time i think i don't have this.
And i don't have a path to public :/, the subdomain point on project/dist.
Do i need nginx?

Comment: If someone have a idea, i'm just don't know what i have to do